# What are my modern options for loading programs and data files on the Apple IIc?

Tags: apple-ii, data-transfer

I've recently acquired an Apple IIc. The internal 5.25" drive does
seem to make appropriate noises at boot, but I do not (at least not
yet) have any floppy disks, with software or otherwise. It's an
earlier 16-RAM-chip motherboard that currently has ROM version 255, in
case that makes any difference.

Given software (both disk images and individual files) and data files
on my Linux system, what currently are my options for getting these on
to the IIc and running/reading them, and, if possible, for copying
back information generated on the IIc? (I also have a Windows system
available, but that's far less convenient for me to use for this
purpose.)

Particularly helpful answers will include details about any
modifications that need to be made to the IIc (including updated ROMs,
if necessary), additional hardware or supplies required by the
solution, such as hardware devices, cables, floppy disks, etc., and
where to get any software required by the solution.

I'm open to solutions that do and do not need actual floppies for the
floppy drive, but of course I'd like to have at least one solution in
reserve that doesn't use the current floppy drive in case it's
irreparably broken.

One of my applications is to do cross-development from my Linux system
(building and doing initial testing of the software on Linux and then
copying it to the actual Apple IIc for further testing), so also
welcome would be comments on how convenient (or not) this would be
with the various solutions you offer.

Answer (score 14):

If you're happy to copy files and use Sneakernet then you could use a disk emulator like [Floppy Emu](https://www.bigmessowires.com/floppy-emu/), [SDFloppy II](http://www.a2heaven.com/webshop/index.php?rt=product/product&path=73&product_id=124), [wDrive](http://kboohk.com/cart/index.php?route=product/category&path=59), etc. (Obviously all product links in this answer are likely to break in the future.)

Note that SmartPort disk emulators require at least a ROM 0 //c. Instructions for upgrading are [given here](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2015/05/29/apple-iic-rom-upgrade/). There are various upgrade kits that include pre-burned ROMs, e.g. [this one](https://www.ebluejay.com/ads/item/4629688) and on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/c-ENHANCEMENT-ROM-3-CHIP-APPLE-IIC-ADDS-UNIDISK-3-5-LIFETIME-WARRNTY-12-/221710345031). Also note that there is a project developing ehancements to Apple's official //c(+) ROMs: [4X and 5X](https://github.com/mgcaret/rom4x).

But really your first port of call should be the amazing [ADTPro](http://adtpro.com/). (It's written in Java, so OK for Linux.)

First you'll need a serial cable. The ADTPro website provides [instructions](http://adtpro.com/connectionsserial.html#DIN5) on how to make one, and a vendor of both [serial cables](http://retrofloppy.com/products/#DIN5DE9) and known good [USB serial adapters](http://retrofloppy.com/products/#USB) (to use if your PC doesn't have an RS-232 port). Also note:

> "... that the original IIc motherboard was not supposed to be able to
>   operate the serial port accurately at speeds higher than 300 baud, but
>   in practice they work fine at all speeds."

For cross-development, ADTPro's ProDOS [Virtual Drive](http://adtpro.com/vdrive.html) feature will likely be of interest. Installing the VSDRIVE driver on a ProDOS disk booted by the //c will allow it to access two virtual hard drives hosted on your PC. You can code on your PC, build into the VSDRIVE drive images, then access them from the //c. (Geo...'s comment suggests you could also host this on a Raspberry Pi.)

To avoid having to insert a disk with VSDRIVE into your //c you could add one of the aforementioned drive emulators, and perhaps [a solution](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2018/05/04/apple-iic-internalexternal-drive-switcher/) to switch between the external and internal drives.

Another option for a turnkey system (hat tip to Brian H for his comment) is using the previously mentioned [ROM 4X](https://github.com/mgcaret/rom4x) with a RAM disk in a2heaven's battery backed RAM card [for the original //c motherboard](http://www.a2heaven.com/webshop/index.php?rt=product/product&path=73&product_id=146) (or [subsequent motherboards with the RAM expansion connector](http://www.a2heaven.com/webshop/index.php?rt=product/product&path=73&product_id=144)).

Comment: VSDRIVE started from a ROMDisk on the Apple IIgs approximates magic!

Comment: Also, after a very cursory look, there are reports of people running the ADTPro server on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.  You can easily enable shell/ftp/samba access to your Pi over the network and probably access your VSDRIVE images that way too!

Comment: @BrianH: Thanks, you reminded me of similar solutions for the //c.

Comment: If one were to open up junk 5.25" floppy, run some loops of wire around the drive-head access area, and then run that coil via resistor to a couple of I/O pins on a microcontroller, I wonder if one could make an interface that could be used to boot an unmodified Apple II without any electrical connection?

Comment: @supercat: Sounds problematic. You need to know which track you're on. Much easier to use the drive connector and emulate the drive like existing solutions.

Comment: @NickWestgate: On boot-up, the system's going to be looking at the first track, and if one uses a custom bootloader one can do whatever one wants after that. 
 Emulating a drive in a fashion consistent with other operating systems would be harder, but with a custom O/S it should be doable.  I don't know if any modern OS would be able to use it, but I have a SmartMedia adapter which, while it requires a custom driver, fits in a 3.5" disk *drive* and uses the drive head for I/O, so the technique has been used on the IBM PC.

Comment: @NickWestgate: Patching something like DOS 3.3 or ProDOS to use such an adapter would require that it look for a special sector header that says "I'm this magic drive" and, if it sees that, attempts to "write" a magic header indicating what track it wants.  On the other hand, the main use I would see for something like this would be as a means of single-shot booting of an unmodified Apple //c whose ROM doesn't support booting an external drive, and I'd expect that a custom loader could use some tricks to achieve faster data transfer than would be possible with an ordinary floppy.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to investigate [ADTPro](http://adtpro.com/).  Since you are using an Apple //c, which already has a serial port, you can easily bootstrap the software by connecting the //c to another computer via a serial cable and/or NULL modem and simply issuing an IN#2 on the Apple.  Once you have ADTPro running, you can start transferring disk images via the serial cable to floppy.   I did this a year or two ago with my Laser 128 and it was super easy to get up and running.